# Создание библиотеки с помощью Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как создать свою мини-библиотеку и подключать её к другим файлам в MS VC++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно используют связку файлов "libname.h" и "libname.cpp". 
В "libname.h" пишут определения классов и объявление функций, а в "libname.cpp" пишут определения этих функций. Если Вам понадобится Ваша библиотека, Вы должны добавить эти два файла в проект и написать

```
#include "libname.h"
```

в тех файлах, где Вы хотите использовать свою библиотеку.

Comment: как правильно создать заголовочный файл ?

Comment: Конкретно в MS VS:
в проекте правый клик по 'Header Files' -> Add -> New item...

Comment: а как правильно его оформлять ?

Comment: Если Вам нужен пример - посмотрите любой проект, скажем, на code.google.com